# Lightning component Quick Action - Hide Modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Does anyone know how to remove the standard modal from the quick action ?

I tried to put that line in the init method but with no success:

```
$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
```

Any idea?

My Controller:

```
    ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();

        var action = component.get("c.getRecordTypeId");
        action.setParams({
            accountId : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var recordTypeId = response.getReturnValue();

                var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                createRecordEvent.setParams({
                    "entityApiName": "Opportunity",
                    "recordTypeId" : recordTypeId,
                    "defaultFieldValues": {
                        'AccountId' : component.get("v.recordId")
                    }
                });
                createRecordEvent.fire();
            } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: '+ state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
should be added in callback method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you all need is implement one interface in component i.e. force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader.

> Components that implement the force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader
>   interface display in a panel without additional controls and are
>   expected to provide a complete user interface for the action.

When used as actions, components that implement the force:lightningQuickAction interface display in a panel with standard action controls, such as a Cancel button. These components can also display and implement their own controls but should be prepared for events from the standard controls.

And in your controller, you can use this **var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                 dismissActionPanel.fire();**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.cloneOpportunity");
        var opp = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({
                "OppId" : component.get("v.recordId")
                });
        action.setCallback(this,function(data){
           var clonedRecordId = data.getReturnValue();        
             helper.navigate(component);
            var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
             dismissActionPanel.fire();

        });
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
})
```

Note:-

> When used as actions, components that implement the
>   force:lightningQuickAction interface display in a panel with standard
>   action controls, such as a Cancel button. These components can also
>   display and implement their own controls, but should be prepared for
>   events from the standard controls.
>
> Components that implement the force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader
>   interface display in a panel without additional controls and are
>   expected to provide a complete user interface for the action.
>
> These interfaces are mutually exclusive. That is, components can
>   implement either the force:lightningQuickAction interface or the
>   force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader interface, but not both. This
>   should make sense; a component can’t both present standard user
>   interface elements and not present standard user interface elements.

Reference:-

1. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_component_actions.htm
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm

**Update:-**

try this:- you were using $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction") not on the right place

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getRecordTypeId");
        action.setParams({
            accountId : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var recordTypeId = response.getReturnValue();
                helper.navigate(component);
                var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                dismissActionPanel.fire();
            }
            else if(state === "ERROR"){
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
            }
                else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: '+ state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Helper class:-

```
({
    navigate : function(component, optyId) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": component.get("v.recordId"),
            "entityApiName": "Opportunity",
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                'AccountId' : component.get("v.recordId")
            }
        });      
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but it still opens the modal just with no header .. is there a way to remove the whole modal ?

Comment: I have edited my response with controller code

Comment: As I said in my original post, I already implemented $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire(); and the modal is still opened.

Comment: @osos9 can you post a screenshot and if possible code snippet ? it is working for me. I have implemented the same in my Org. I am able to kill the modal .

Comment: I edited my post with the code of the controller

Comment: @osos9 try with my updated answer. Tell me if you still face any problem. refresh your page 2-3 times before checking.

Comment: It worked, thanks. It still opens but then disappears so I guess that's ok for now, thanks.

Comment: yes, that is what we are doing. We are killing the modal once it tries to open. Mark this as your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best solution I could get so far. The style tag will simply hide the modal, while shows the spinner plus it doesn't collapse the browser vertical scrollbar.

```
<aura:component description="InstallAlarmQAction"
            implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId"
            access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" class="slds-show backgroundSpinner" size="medium" />

<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-backdrop {
        background: rgba(43, 40, 38, 0) !important;
    }
    .backgroundSpinner{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    }
    .modal-body {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    .closeIcon {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .desktop {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
</aura:html>
```

You'll have to use setTimeout to make 'e.force:closeQuickAction' work. If you don't fire it at all, the UI will freeze. Here's the controller:

```
({ doInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
setTimeout(function () {$A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();}, 1500); }})
```